# Are there ways to optimize Approve and Transfer?

Tags: tokens

Let's take the following use case:

```
I want to allow a smart contract to transfer some erc20 token (from another contract) for me.
```

So what i assume i should do is:

1. Create and publish an approve transaction.
2. Wait for the tx to be included in a block
3. Call the smart contract's method to transfer the token

However, i realise than i can also publish both transactions one right after the other and hope for both to be included in the same block, or at least the approve tx to be included first than the transfer tx. Both scenarios work.

My question is, Is it wise to let the gasPrice be a little higher in the approve transaction to make sure it gets place in a block either first or at the same time as the transfer transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions include a `nonce` value which tracks the number of transactions sent from an address.

When submitting multiple transactions to the blockchain from the same account, the transactions will always be processed in `nonce` order. i.e. a transaction with `nonce` 4 will not be processed until transactions 0-3 get processed. Thus you need not worry about setting slightly higher gas price in this situation since transaction order will be deterministic.

Read this chapter/section in the Mastering Ethereum book: 
[Transactions - The Transaction Nonce](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/transactions.asciidoc#the-transaction-nonce)

Comment: Perfect! That makes sense.